# Implement scrapy as a service throws: [send URLs dynamically to the scrapy]

Tags: python, scrapy

How can I implement Scrapy as a service that receives an URL and start the crawling? So far, I implemented the service as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

app = Flask(__name__)
crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())


@app.route('/crawl', methods=['POST'])
def crawl():
    urls = request.json.get('urls', [])  # Assuming URLs are passed as a JSON array in the request body

    if urls:
        # Start the crawling process with the specified URLs
        crawler_process.crawl(MySpider, start_urls=urls)
        crawler_process.start()

        return 'Crawling started.'
    else:
        return 'No URLs provided.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I send the following request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"urls":["https://example.com"]}' http://localhost:5000/crawl
```

It gives me:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread of the main interpreter
```

I also tried `CrawlRunner` but still gave me the same error.